# Google Cloud Speech To Text Giving 0 result

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I'm using Google Cloud Speech to text api in Java.

I'm getting 0 results when I call speechClient.recognize

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-speech</artifactId>
    <version>0.80.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

Java code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.api.gax.core.FixedCredentialsProvider;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionAudio;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognizeResponse;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechRecognitionAlternative;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechRecognitionResult;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechSettings;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;

public class SpeechToText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Instantiates a client
        try {

            String jsonFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/serviceaccount.json";
            FileInputStream credentialsStream = new FileInputStream(jsonFilePath);
            GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsStream);
            FixedCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials);

            SpeechSettings speechSettings = 
                    SpeechSettings.newBuilder()
                        .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                        .build();       

            SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.create(speechSettings);

            //SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.create();

            // The path to the audio file to transcribe         
            String fileName = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/call-recording-790.opus";

            // Reads the audio file into memory
            Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            ByteString audioBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);

            System.out.println(path.toAbsolutePath());

            // Builds the sync recognize request
            RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder().setEncoding(AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
                    .setSampleRateHertz(8000).setLanguageCode("en-US").build();

            RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder().setContent(audioBytes).build();

            System.out.println("recognize builder");

            // Performs speech recognition on the audio file
            RecognizeResponse response = speechClient.recognize(config, audio);
            List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.getResultsList();

            System.out.println(results.size()); // ***** HERE 0

            for (SpeechRecognitionResult result : results) {

                // There can be several alternative transcripts for a given chunk of speech.
                // Just use the
                // first (most likely) one here.
                SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
                System.out.printf("Transcription: %s%n", alternative.getTranscript());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, I'm getting results.size as 0. When I upload the same opus file on demo at https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/, it gives output text correctly.

So why is the recognize call giving zero results?

Comment: It is so long time ago but I want to try my chance. Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @Sha Don't remember any more now :)

Answer (score 0):

There could be 3 reasons for Speech-to-Text to return an empty response:

1. Audio is not clear.
2. Audio is not intelligible.
3. Audio is not using the proper encoding.

From what I can see, reason 3 is the most possible cause of your issue. To resolve this,  check this [page](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/troubleshooting#returns_an_empty_response) to know how to verify the encoding of your audio file which must match the parameters you sent in InitialRecognizeRequest.